# Java API which will compress the xls file in xls format

Tags: java, excel

I am having an `excel` file but the file size is to large,
do you have any suggestion so that we can reduce the file size in the same format?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few common tricks to reduce the size of an Excel document *while keeping it in Excel format*.  It depends on the specific format / Excel version of the file.

- For example converting the newer ".xlsx" format to .xls format may introduce some loss of features, but will sometimes produce a smaller file  (sometimes bigger...!).   The resulting file remains "Excel compatible" (albeit with the possibly loss of feature such as text formatting or loss of data for eg. with more than 64k rows, etc. as mentioned earlier).
- for XLSX format, it is possible to un-archive the file (xlsx is a zip file in disguise) and to re-compress its contents using a more aggressive ZIP compression.  Attention the format needs to remain ZIP but may be done with a different setting (by allowing for a slower process and/or a bigger buffer we typically squeeze a few more percentage points of compression ratio).
- At the level of the XLS file format/structure itself, it is possible in some cases to "repack" the file in ways that reduce the file size compared to the original.
- There are also a few tricks which alter the effective payload content of the file, but do not change the looks of it.  For example by forcing empty cells to share the same format as surrounding cells, one can avoid the inefficient storage of "sparse tables" by making more of the sheets have fewer "holes".

Now, many of these "recipes" are somewhat ad-hoc, version dependent, content dependent and overall brittle or unreliable. But there must be a bit of a science to this as I believe some commercial products specialize in XLS (or more generally MS-Office) document compression.

While there are java libraries that make compressing and decompressing ZIP archives easier, or also XLS file parsing or creating easier, I do not know of libraries that are dedicated to the sole purpose of squeezing Excel files.